# ASP.Net Core MVC Dependency Injection not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am trying to inject a interface into to my HomeController and I am getting this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' while attempting to activate

My Startup class is as follows:

```
public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton(provider => Configuration);

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}

public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app, 
    IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

        try
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices
                .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                .CreateScope())
            {
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider
                        .GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()
                        .Database.Migrate();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());

    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseIdentity();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.Run((async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Error");
    }));
}
```

and my HomeController constructor is:

```
public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration, IEmailSender mailService)
{
    _mailService = mailService;
    _to = configuration["emailAddress.Support"];
}
```

Please tell me where I am mistaken.

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)

Comment: I would recommend isolating your `Configuration` from your `Controller` by creating a POCO to store whatever configuration details you want passed, and injecting that instead.

Comment: The similar error can happen if constructor has object as a parameter, but service configured as interface https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-whil

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try injecting it as an `IConfigurationRoot` instead of `IConfiguration`:

```
 public HomeController(IConfigurationRoot configuration
    , IEmailSender mailService)
{
    _mailService = mailService;
    _to = configuration["emailAddress.Support"];
}
```

In this case, the line

```
services.AddSingleton(provider => Configuration);
```

is equivalent to

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(provider => Configuration);
```

because the `Configuration` property on the class is declared as such, and injection will be done by matching whatever type it was registered as. We can replicate this pretty easily, which might make it clearer:

```
public interface IParent { }

public interface IChild : IParent { }

public class ConfigurationTester : IChild { }
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    IChild example = new ConfigurationTester();
    services.AddSingleton(provider => example);
}
```

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(IParent configuration)
    {
        // this will blow up
    }
}
```

### However

As stephen.vakil mentioned in the comments, it would be better to load your configuration file into a class, and then inject that class into controllers as needed. That would look something like this:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

You can grab these configurations with the `IOptions` interface:

```
public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
```

Comment: Why?  I do not do this in my code and it still works fine.  And it is not done in this order in the docs:  http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html

Comment: @stephen.vakil You're right, I was totally wrong on that detail. Thanks for the link! I have updated my answer, Jam.

Comment: That was it! can you explain what the difference is?

Comment: Inject it as an `IConfiguration` for greater flexibility.

Answer (score 9):

In Core 2.0 it's recommended to use IConfiguration instead of IConfigurationRoot

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/#add-configuration-providers

Answer (score 2):

When moving a project from .Net Core 1.x to 2.0, change all `IConfigurationRoot` to `IConfiguration`