# Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft Extensions Configuration IConfiguration

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am getting this error, could not understand for the life of me.

**Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.FeatureManagement.ConfigurationFeatureSettingsProvider'.**

This is a simple .net core 2.2 console app, with the following nuget packages added.

1. [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/2.1.1)
2. [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/2.1.1)
3. [Microsoft.FeatureManagement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.FeatureManagement/2.0.0-preview-010610001-1263)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.FeatureManagement;
using Microsoft.FeatureManagement.FeatureFilters;

namespace ConfigurationConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string FeatureName = "Beta";

            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddSingleton(configuration).AddFeatureManagement().AddFeatureFilter<PercentageFilter>().AddFeatureFilter<AccountIdFilter>();
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var featureManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFeatureManager>();
            var enabled = await featureManager.IsEnabledAsync(FeatureName);
            Console.WriteLine($"The {FeatureName} feature is {(enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled")} ");
        }
    }
}

// The following are the command for the packages.

dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json --version 2.1.1
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection --version 2.1.1
dotnet add package Microsoft.FeatureManagement --version 2.0.0-preview-010610001-1263
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection error: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-whil)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ok, here it is after hours of hair pulling.

```
services.AddSingleton(configuration).AddFeatureManagement().AddFeatureFilter<PercentageFilter>().AddFeatureFilter<AccountIdFilter>();

should be 

services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration).AddFeatureManagement().AddFeatureFilter<PercentageFilter>().AddFeatureFilter<AccountIdFilter>();
```

Note the generic `<IConfiguration>`

Also I have noted that declaring configuration object as IConfiguration will also do the trick. Using ***var*** to declare configuration is giving the problem. Instead of ***var*** use **IConfiguration**. Then again the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for commenting this as an answer, but the above code be careful if you are using it inside a new project. It goes still into the root to search for it, might cause issues when you have 2 projects with the same application.Environment.json

> var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();