# Sharing a data access layer between ASP.NET Core and .NET Core Windows Forms app

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, connection-string

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

I have been sharing a data access layer between my ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app and my .NET Core 3.1 Windows Forms backend app through a class library pattern.

This has been working fine up until I decided to transition the data access layer to be injected using dependency injection.

I have successfully setup the Windows Forms app to use dependency injection, however this version of Windows Forms doesn't use `appsettings.json` and therefore doesn't use an `IConfiguration` instance to pass the connection string. Instead I access the connection string through `Settings.settings` in the solution dependencies like so:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString
```

I have tried to build an `IConfiguration` object to read from `Properties.Settings.Default` but I can't seem to find a method to instantiate an `IConfigurationSection` to populate `ConnectionStrings` section in `IConfiguration` so that the

```
GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")
```

call will work.

So my question is: can I reconfigure the Windows Forms .NET Core app to use `AppSettings.json`? Or is there a way to build an instance of `IConfiguration` that can be populated by `Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString`? Or is there a much better way of handling this situation that I haven't considered?

Any help is good help at the moment.

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: Thanks for the response but I really don't know in this particular instance what can I reproduce?

Comment: I am struggling to see the issue, why would the use of dependency injection change where you can access whatever configuration settings you had before?

Comment: Can you find answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114527/simplest-way-to-have-a-configuration-file-in-a-windows-forms-c-sharp-application)? Add key in the configuration/appsettings section, then use System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyKey"];

Comment: @BenMatthews So that I can use the same class library between the two project types.  Asp.Net Core uses AppSettings.json kvp accessed through IConfiguration interface whereas the windows forms app uses a different method.  I thought about it and I think I am going recreate the windows forms solution as a core 3.1 from the start and import all of my class libraries and forms.  It was originally a .net core 5.0 app and I think that might be why I am having problems.   If it works I will post that as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I came across the post, [Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft Extensions Configuration IConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59332463/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfigura), and then just copied the `appsettings.json` over from my ASP.NET app and everything is working.

All I had to do was add `.SetBasePath(@"mypath")` and remove some things that didn't apply to my project. Here is the code that did the trick in the end:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(@"mypath").AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            IConfiguration configuration = builder.Build();
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);`
```