# Why does .net core Dependency injection not work for me?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use the .net core DI in my console app. When I write something like this (the code below is located in my Program.cs):

```
    private static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices()
    {
            IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            ConfigurationOptions configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                ConnectionString = "my-connection-string",
                StoredProceduresPath = "my-path",
                PathToGeneralFolder = "D:\\XmlFiles",
                PathToInvalidFolder = "D:\\InvalidXmlFiles",
                LogName = "Log",
                Source = "Source",
                SecretHashPassword = "my-sercet-password",
                DataAccessTimeoutMs = 30_000
            };

            IOptions<ConfigurationOptions> options = Options.Create(configurationOptions);

            DatabaseTransactionManager databaseTransactionManager = new DatabaseTransactionManager();
            DbContext DbContext = new DbContext(
                options,
                databaseTransactionManager);

            UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository(DbContext);
            SoftwareRepository softwareRepository = new SoftwareRepository(DbContext);
            SoftwareModuleRepository softwareModuleRepository = new SoftwareModuleRepository(DbContext);
            DeviceRepository deviceRepository = new DeviceRepository(DbContext);

            LoggerService loggerService = new LoggerService(options);
            XmlService xmlService = new XmlService(options);
            SqlService sqlService = new SqlService(
                deviceRepository,
                softwareModuleRepository,
                softwareRepository);
            FolderService folderService = new FolderService(
                options,
                cancellationTokenSource,
                cancellationTokenSource.Token,
                sqlService,
                loggerService,
                xmlService);

            services.AddScoped(serivceProvider => folderService);

            return services;
    }
```

my FolderService is properly initialized and works with no problems, but when I try to inject everything in a "normal" way (located in my Program.cs as well):

```
private static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices()
        {
            IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

            services.Configure<ConfigurationOptions>(configOptions => configuration.GetSection("ConfigurationOptions"));
            services.AddScoped<CancellationTokenSource>();
            services.AddScoped<ITransactionManager, DatabaseTransactionManager>();
            services.AddScoped<IDbContext, DbContext>();

            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ISoftwareRepository, SoftwareRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ISoftwareModuleRepository, SoftwareModuleRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IDeviceRepository, DeviceRepository>();

            services.AddScoped<ILoggerService, LoggerService>();
            services.AddScoped<IXmlService, XmlService>();
            services.AddScoped<ISqlService, SqlService>();
            services.AddScoped<IFolderService, FolderService>();
            return services;
        }
```

...while debugging I see that FolderService is null. What am I doing wrong?
my appsettings.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "ConfigurationOptions": {
    "ConnectionString": "some-connection-string",
    "StoredProceduresPath": "some-path",
    "PathToGeneralFolder": "D:\\XmlFiles",
    "PathToInvalidFolder": "D:\\InvalidXmlFiles",
    "LogName": "Log",
    "Source": "Source",
    "SecretHashPassword": "my-sercet-password",
    "DataAccessTimeoutMs": 30000
  }
}
```

FolderService class (constructor part):

```
public class FolderService : IFolderService
    {
        private readonly string generalFolder;

        private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
        private readonly CancellationToken cancellationToken;

        private readonly ISqlService sqlService;
        private readonly ILoggerService loggerHelper;
        private readonly IXmlService xmlHelper;

        public FolderService(IOptions<ConfigurationOptions> options,
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
            ISqlService sqlService, ILoggerService loggerHelper, IXmlService xmlHelper)
        {
            this.generalFolder = options.Value.PathToGeneralFolder;

            this.cancellationTokenSource = cancellationTokenSource;
            this.cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

            this.sqlService = sqlService;
            this.loggerHelper = loggerHelper;
            this.xmlHelper = xmlHelper;
        }
}
```

Full Program.cs

```
private static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices()
        {
            IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

            #region As it must be
            services.Configure<ConfigurationOptions>(configOptions => configuration.GetSection("ConfigurationOptions"));
            services.AddScoped<CancellationTokenSource>();
            services.AddScoped<ITransactionManager, DatabaseTransactionManager>();
            services.AddScoped<IDbContext, DbContext>();

            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ISoftwareRepository, SoftwareRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ISoftwareModuleRepository, SoftwareModuleRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IDeviceRepository, DeviceRepository>();

            services.AddScoped<ILoggerService, LoggerService>();
            services.AddScoped<IXmlService, XmlService>();
            services.AddScoped<ISqlService, SqlService>();
            services.AddScoped<IFolderService, FolderService>();
            #endregion

            #region As it works by now
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            ConfigurationOptions configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                ConnectionString = "not-important",
                StoredProceduresPath = "not-important",
                PathToGeneralFolder = "D:\\XmlFiles",
                PathToInvalidFolder = "D:\\InvalidXmlFiles",
                LogName = "ButsenkoLog",
                Source = "NektarinSource",
                SecretHashPassword = "my-sercet-password",
                DataAccessTimeoutMs = 30_000
            };

            IOptions<ConfigurationOptions> options = Options.Create(configurationOptions);

            DatabaseTransactionManager databaseTransactionManager = new DatabaseTransactionManager();
            DbContext dbContext = new DbContext(
                options,
                databaseTransactionManager);

            UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository(dbContext);
            SoftwareRepository softwareRepository = new SoftwareRepository(dbContext);
            SoftwareModuleRepository softwareModuleRepository = new SoftwareModuleRepository(dbContext);
            DeviceRepository deviceRepository = new DeviceRepository(dbContext);

            LoggerService loggerService = new LoggerService(options);
            XmlService xmlService = new XmlService(options);
            SqlService sqlService = new SqlService(
                deviceRepository,
                softwareModuleRepository,
                softwareRepository);
            FolderService folderService = new FolderService(
                options,
                cancellationTokenSource,
                cancellationTokenSource.Token,
                sqlService,
                loggerService,
                xmlService);

            services.AddScoped(serivceProvider => folderService);
            #endregion

            return services;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IServiceCollection services = ConfigureServices();
            ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            FolderService folderService = serviceProvider.GetService<FolderService>();

            HostFactory.Run(configurator =>
            {
                configurator.RunAsLocalSystem();

                configurator.Service<FolderService>(serviceConfigurator =>
                {
                    serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(() => folderService);

                    serviceConfigurator.WhenStarted((service, hostControl) =>
                    {
                        service.Start();
                        return true;
                    });

                    serviceConfigurator.WhenStopped((service, hostControl) =>
                    {
                        service.Stop();
                        return true;
                    });
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Where do you inject it? Could you share Program.cs?

Comment: All the parameters in your FolderService contructor also need to be injected dependencies/services. Is this true?

Comment: This shouldnt have anything to do with your appsettings... Does `FolderService` implement `IFolderService`?

Comment: @ilkerkaran actually it is injected in Program.cs, I get this FolderService instance in Main method
`IServiceCollection services = ConfigureServices();
            ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            FolderService folderService = serviceProvider.GetService<FolderService>();`

Comment: @maccettura yeap, sure

Comment: @el_nektarin So you arent injecting dependencies through the constructors?

Comment: `public FolderService(IOptions<ConfigurationOptions> ops,
            CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
            ISqlService sqlService, ILoggerService loggerHelper, IXmlService xmlHelper)
        {
            this.generalFolder = ops.Value.PathToGeneralFolder;
            this.cancellationTokenSource = cancelTokenSource;
            this.cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            this.sqlService = sqlService;
            this.loggerHelper = loggerHelper;
            this.xmlHelper = xmlHelper;
        }`

Comment: @maccettura see my constructor above, sorry for code formatting

Comment: Could you post all file service code above in your question and also post the code where you are injecting it? You should be able to edit your question with it

Comment: @chrisbuttacavoli done, you can look at it.

Comment: Have you tried moving all of your static properties inside the Main method of your program? It could be that it is unable to resolve the type because they are all static properties

Comment: @el_nektarin you are trying to get the wrong service. You registered it as `IFolderService` but in the main method you try to get `FolderService`. I think it should be like `var folderService = serviceProvider.GetService<IFolderService>();`

Comment: @ilkerkaran ok, I did like you said and now I'm getting `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Threading.CancellationToken' while attempting to activate 'ConsoleAppWindowsService.BusinessLogicImplenemtations.FolderService'.'`

Comment: Means you also need to resolve `CancellationToken`. Check from here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-whil

Comment: I will add it as an aswer if you are happy with it

Comment: @ilkerkaran ok, I got your point. At least it is trying to create an instance, so my main issue is solved. Get your deserved +1 for your point on `IFolderService`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Register your class as `IFolderService` but you try to get it via service by calling like `serviceProvider.GetService<FolderService>();` 
It should be;

```
var folderService = serviceProvider.GetService<IFolderService>();
```

And as long as all constructor parameters resolve successfully you are good to go.