# Unable to resolve service for type 'TestService' while attempting to activate 'TestsController'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My error

`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'KTS.BLL.Interfaces.ITestService' while attempting to activate 'KTS.WEBAPI.Controllers.TestsController'.`

I have 3 layer architecture app. TestController is in a API layer, ITestService and TestService are in BLL.

TestController

```
    [ApiController]
    public class TestsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ITestService _testService;

        IMapper mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<TestDTO, TestModel>()).CreateMapper();
        public TestsController(ITestService testService)
        {
            _testService = testService;
        }

        // GET: api/Tests
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<TestModel> GetTests()
        {
            return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TestDTO>, IEnumerable<TestModel>>(_testService.GetAllTests());
        }
    }
```

TestService

```
    public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        IUnitOfWork Database { get; set; }

        IMapper mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Test, TestDTO>()).CreateMapper();
        public TestService(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            Database = uow;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TestDTO> GetAllTests()
        {
            return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Test>, List<TestDTO>>(Database.Tests.GetAll());
        }
    }
```

I know, that there are a lot of topics like my, but they don't help me. I have tried to add `services.AddTransient<ITestService, TestService>();` to my Startup.cs but is doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I add

```
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>();
            services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, EFUnitOfWork>();
            services.AddTransient<ITestService, TestService>();
```

to Startup.cs

Answer (score 1):

Did you register IUnitOfWork before TestService in startup.cs?
It could be the case.

Check out [hsop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52047414/6671523) on this post. It looks similiar to the problem you're having.

Comment: When I register IUnitOfWork, I get new error: 
Unable to resolve service for type 'KTS.DAL.EF.ApplicationContext' while attempting to activate 'KTS.DAL.Repositories.EFUnitOfWork'.