# ASP.NET Core Web API InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp-net-core-spa-services

i'm trying to build a simple api as a test to a future api for a project. But i keep having this error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'AspnetCore_WebApi.Models.TarefaContext' while attempting to activate
> 'AspnetCore_WebApi.Models.TarefaRepositorio'.

Here is TarefaContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace AspnetCore_WebApi.Models
{
    public class TarefaContext : DbContext
    {
        public TarefaContext(DbContextOptions<TarefaContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }
        public DbSet<TarefaItem> TarefaItens { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TarefaRepositorio.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace AspnetCore_WebApi.Models
{
    public class TarefaRepositorio : ITarefaRepositorio
    {
        private readonly TarefaContext _context;
        public TarefaRepositorio(TarefaContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            Add(new TarefaItem { Nome = "Item1" });
        }
        public IEnumerable<TarefaItem> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.TarefaItens.ToList();
        }
        public void Add(TarefaItem item)
        {
            _context.TarefaItens.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        public TarefaItem Find(long key)
        {
            return _context.TarefaItens.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Chave == key);
        }
        public void Remove(long key)
        {
            var entity = _context.TarefaItens.First(t => t.Chave == key);
            _context.TarefaItens.Remove(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void Update(TarefaItem item)
        {
            _context.TarefaItens.Update(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

TarefaController.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AspnetCore_WebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace AspnetCore_WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TarefaController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ITarefaRepositorio _tarefaRepositorio;
        public TarefaController(ITarefaRepositorio tarefaRepositorio)
        {
            _tarefaRepositorio = tarefaRepositorio;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<TarefaItem> GetAll()
        {
            return _tarefaRepositorio.GetAll();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTarefa")]
        public IActionResult GetById(long id)
        {
            var item = _tarefaRepositorio.Find(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return new ObjectResult(item);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody] TarefaItem item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            _tarefaRepositorio.Add(item);
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetTarefa", new { id = item.Chave }, item);
        }
    }
}
```

ITarefaRepositorio.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace AspnetCore_WebApi.Models
{
    public interface ITarefaRepositorio
    {
        void Add(TarefaItem item);
        IEnumerable<TarefaItem> GetAll();
        TarefaItem Find(long key);
        void Remove(long key);
        void Update(TarefaItem item);
    }
}
```

Comment: The way an IoC container (like `ServiceProvider`) works is that in order to create one type (the controller) it sees that it needs to create a repository. To create the repository it sees that it needs to create the context. For that to work each type has to be registered at startup with the `ServiceCollection`. It's telling you that `TarefaContext` hasn't been registered. It doesn't know how to create one, so it can't create the respository. So `TarefaContext` has to be registered at startup with the `ServiceProvider`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40900520/1743997

Comment: @ScottHannen thank you! I didn't tought about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message describes that dependency injection cannot resolve your TarefaContext class. You should register your db context in your startup `ConfigureServices` method using `services.AddDbContext` method.
For more information see Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch! I forgot to mention that I'm using EF Core In Memory, so I just change a few things in it.

Answer (score 0):

As [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5101046/scott-hannen) and [Artis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13454461/artis-vilcins) said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62643033/12934203 I haven't added my Context Class to the startup.cs file. I had some trouble with the article mentioned by [Artis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13454461/artis-vilcins) because I'm using EF Core InMemory so I jus had to add

```
services.AddDbContext<TarefaContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase());
```

to the ConfigureServices at Startup.cs instead

```
services.AddDbContext<TarefaContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=someDB.db"));
```

Thank y'all for helping