# How can I always send a specific value for a given type in an ASP.NET Core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm loading some endpoints defined in external assemblies, into my web app on startup with:

```
// Add channel endpoints.
var endpointsFolder = Configuration.GetSection("EndpointsFolder").Get<string>();
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(endpointsFolder))
    services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(Assembly.LoadFrom(file));
```

All of the loaded endpoints derive from a custom class called `SecureEndpoint` which requires an interface `ISecurityContext`:

```
[ApiEndpoint]
public class SecureEndpoint : ControllerBase {
    public SecureEndpoint(ISecurityContext securityContext) { ... }
}
```

So, for example:

```
[Route("test")]
public sealed class TestEndpoint : SecureEndpoint {
    public TestEndpoint(ISecurityContext securityContext) : base(securityContext) { ... }
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get() {
        return "This is a test.";
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I invoke the endpoint, I get an error saying:

> `System.InvalidOperationException`: Unable to resolve service for type `Namespacing.ISecurityContext` while attempting to activate `Namespacing.TestEndpoint`.

A few searches on the matter give [a pretty simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-whil):

```
services.AddScoped<ISecurityContext, SecurityContext>();
```

However, I have one problem; `ISecurityContext` is given to me in the form of the interface only. The value that is given to me, is the value I should use everywhere it's required. As a result, I need a way to say "if `ISecurityContext` is needed, use *this* value".

---

Is there a way to always send a specific value for a given type?

***Edit**: `services.AddSingleton(...)` did the trick, but I don't have time to type an answer up for it currently. I'll circle back later this afternoon.*

<sub>*If there are any compilation issues, they are only the result of typing this question.*</sub>

Comment: I think I need `services.AddSingleton`, testing it now.

Comment: Maybe singleton, but if your IServiceContext instance is not thread-safe you should try to register it as a scoped service.

Comment: @tia thanks for the heads up! `services.AddSingleton` did the trick!