# Can I inject instance of concrete types as singleton in my Startup class in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing an ASP.NET-based library. I need to hold an instance of `System.Reflection.MethodInfo` throughout the lifecycle of the app which uses the library, hence I thought of holding it in services as a singleton.
Here's my startup class:

```cs
public class NewStartup {
      private MethodInfo method;
      public NewStartup(MethodInfo m) {
        method = m;
      } 

      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
          services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
      }

      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
      {
          app.UseRouting();
          // app.UseMiddleware<NewMiddleware>();
          applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => Server.SetSocketPermissions());
      }
    }
```

class `NewMiddleware` also has a similar constructor.

Now, I have a `Server.cs` file which provisions the HTTP server for me:

```cs
sealed class Server
    {
        internal static void SetSocketPermissions() { } // Irrelevant

        private IHost newPrepareServer(MethodInfo m)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices(services => {
                  services.AddSingleton(typeof(MethodInfo), m); // Adding my value in services here
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                    .UseStartup<NewStartup>() // Construct a NewStartup object by injecting MethodInfo instance.
                    .UseKestrel(opt => { }); // Irrelevant
                })
              .Build();

        }

        public void Run(MethodInfo method) {
          var server = this.newPrepareServer(method);
          server.Run();
        }
    }
```

I am getting the error `Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.NewStartup'.`

I checked in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addsingleton(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-type-system-object)) and it says I should be able to do `services.AddSingleton(Type serviceType, object instance)` and a similar solution suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40900520), but it doesn't seem to work for me. I tried writing an interface that provides `MethodInfo GetMethodInfo()` API and writing a concrete type that wraps MethodInfo and implements this interface, I am seeing the same error with a different type. Something tells me that I am doing this bit correctly, but something wrong somewhere else. Can I please get some help on this?

Comment: did you find an answer? I have come across the same issue

Comment: @VergilC. No. I had to implement my own singleton for this case. I don't think it is the most idiomatic approach here though.