# System.AggregateException in API "Some services are not able to be constructed"

Tags: c#, wcf

In my API I have to wrap a WCF service, I added the reference to the project and
I added this to IServiceCollection

```
services.AddScoped<IServiceClient, ServiceClient>(sp =>
  new ServiceClient($"{configuration.GetValue<string>(Constant.Url)}"));
```

---

My ServiceClient Class :

```
public class ServiceClient: IServiceClient 
{

  private string urlService;

  // WCF Service to wrapp
  private WCFServiceReference.WCFServiceServiceClient _WCFServiceServiceClient; 

  public ServiceClient(string urlService) 
  {
    this.urlService = urlService;
    BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    this._WCFServiceServiceClient = new WCFServiceReference.WCFServiceServiceClient(basicHttpBinding, new EndpointAddress(this.urlService));
  }

  public Task<CalculateResponse> CalculateAsync(Request input) 
  {
    return CalculateAsync(input, CancellationToken.None);
  }

  public Task<GetProductListResponse> GetProductListAsync(ProductRequest input) 
  {
    return GetElencoProdottiAsync(input, CancellationToken.None);
  }

  public Task<GetVariableOfProductResponse> GetVariableOfProductAsync(GetVariableRequest input) 
  {
    return GetVariableOfProductAsync(input, CancellationToken.None);
  }

  private Task<GetProductListResponse> GetProductListAsync(ProductRequest input, CancellationToken none
  {
    return this._WCFServiceServiceClient.GetProductListAsync(input);
  }

  private Task<GetVariableOfProductResponse> GetVariableOfProductAsync(GetVariableRequest input, CancellationToken none) 
  {
    return this._WCFServiceServiceClient.GetVariableOfProductAsync(input);
  }

  private Task<CalculateResponse> CalculateAsync(Request input, CancellationToken none) 
  {
    return this._WCFServiceServiceClient.CalculateAsync(input);
  }

}
```

When I start my application, this call `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();`
in Main rises the following Excpetion:

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Namespace.IProductService
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Namespace.ProductService': Unable
> to resolve service for type 'Namespace.ServiceClient' while attempting
> to activate 'Namespace.ProductService'.)

Answer (score 0):

What does your **ProductService** Service Lifetime?

*Singleton* can't resolve Scope service

Comment: ProductService Service Lifetime is Scoped

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this, you can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-whil) for specifics.

```
 public class ServiceClient : IServiceClient
    {
      ...
       public ServiceClient(IServiceClient ServiceClient)
       {
           ...
       }
    }
```