# .NET 6 ... unable to resolve service for type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm using NuGet packages in VS 2022:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Connected to my SQL server (all good), all my models partial classes generated.  I add a new controller (Add New Scaffolded Item) and select "MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework".  Select my Model class "Phonenumbertype" my Data context class "JMSContext" (just web API no front end tested thru Swagger).  My controller gets generated

```
namespace WebAppTest.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PhonenumbertypesController : ControllerBase
    {

    // Error out with code generated:
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-6.0
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0

    // Possible Solution
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-whil

    private readonly JMSContext _context;

    public PhonenumbertypesController(JMSContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Phonenumbertypes
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Phonenumbertype>>> GetPhonenumbertypes()
    {
        return await _context.Phonenumbertypes.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/Phonenumbertypes/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Phonenumbertype>> GetPhonenumbertype(short id)
    {
        var phonenumbertype = await _context.Phonenumbertypes.FindAsync(id);

        if (phonenumbertype == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return phonenumbertype;
    }

    // PUT: api/Phonenumbertypes/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutPhonenumbertype(short id, Phonenumbertype phonenumbertype)
    {
        if (id != phonenumbertype.PhtId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(phonenumbertype).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!PhonenumbertypeExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Phonenumbertypes
    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Phonenumbertype>> PostPhonenumbertype(Phonenumbertype phonenumbertype)
    {
        _context.Phonenumbertypes.Add(phonenumbertype);
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (PhonenumbertypeExists(phonenumbertype.PhtId))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetPhonenumbertype", new { id = phonenumbertype.PhtId }, phonenumbertype);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Phonenumbertypes/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePhonenumbertype(short id)
    {
        var phonenumbertype = await _context.Phonenumbertypes.FindAsync(id);
        if (phonenumbertype == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Phonenumbertypes.Remove(phonenumbertype);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return NoContent();
    }

    private bool PhonenumbertypeExists(short id)
    {
        return _context.Phonenumbertypes.Any(e => e.PhtId == id);
    }
   }
}
```

I run my web API, Swagger starts, select my API (Try Out) and get Error: response status is 500 and the following body:

***System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WebAppTest.Models.JMSContext' while attempting to activate 'WebAppTest.Controllers.PhonenumbertypesController'.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
at lambda_method9(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )....***

This is all auto-generated code so my expectations was that is would work and I would expand my code from there ... this is just a basic test.

It was able to get the results I wanted by removing all the auto-generated code in controller class ... BUT, I'm trying to figure out why the auto-generated code doesn't work?

Comment: The problem might be injecting `JMSContext`, is the service initialized in Startup.cs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auto generated code assumes you have setup dependency registration already. In your case you have not added `JMSContext` to the dependency container.

You need to add JMSContext to the DI

If you are using the file `Startup.cs` you can do

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<JMSContext>(options 
           => options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString(
                  "YourConnectionStringKeyName_From_AppSettings.json")
  );
  //----- rest of the code
}
```

If you only use the file `Program.cs` before building the app, you can use

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<JMSContext>(options 
    => options.UseSqlServer(
           Configuration.GetConnectionString(
               "YourConnectionStringKeyName_From_AppSettings.json")
);
```

Comment: Thank you ... that resolved the issue.  I don't have a Startup.cs, using Program.cs.  Added the following: using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;  and after the builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen() I added the line: builder.Services.AddDbContext<WebAppTest.Models.JMSContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("mydata connection string"));

Comment: Yes this worked. However, for Program.cs I used `builder.Services.AddDbContext<NorthwindContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

which means using `builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString` to get the connection string through name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resovle the JMSContext class in the startup.cs class like [this](https://davecallan.com/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-error/).
More on [Dependency injection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)

Comment: While those link can answer, such as they can expire, can you include more revelant parts into post ?