# Error 500 when try to post to database on .net 6

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have problem in my .Net project with my Controller/service.
My program works but if I want to register user in Postman program throw error 500 as at the bottom.
I really have no idea whats the problem, it works few changes ago.
Can someone explain me why it stop working?

.net 6

DbContext:

```
     public class TrainingAppContext : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<User>? User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Calendar>? Calendar { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Exercises>? Exercises { get; set; }
        public TrainingAppContext(DbContextOptions<TrainingAppContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .Property(r => r.Name);
            
    }

    public static implicit operator string(TrainingAppContext v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Controller:

```
[

Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]

public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    public AuthController(LoginService loginService)
    {
        _loginService = loginService;
    }
    private LoginService _loginService;
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public IActionResult Login([FromBody] User user)
    {
        bool checkUserLogIn = _loginService.CheckUserLogIn(user.Name, user.Password);
    if (checkUserLogIn)
    {
        var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"));
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var claims = new[] {
          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
          };

        var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken
        (
        issuer: "https://localhost:5001",
        audience: "https://localhost:5001",
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
        signingCredentials: signingCredentials
        );
        var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);

        return Ok(new { Token = tokenString });


    }
    else
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }
}
[HttpPost("Register")]

public IActionResult Register([FromBody] User user)
{
    bool CheckName = _loginService.CheckUserExist(user.Name);
    if (!CheckName)
    {
        if (_loginService.AddUser(user.Name, user.Password, user.Trainer))
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else return BadRequest();   
    }
    else
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }


        

    
}
```

service:

```
public class LoginService
    {
        private TrainingAppContext _context;

        public LoginService(TrainingAppContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }



        public bool CheckUserLogIn(string name, string password)
        {

   


            if(_context.User.Where(x => x.Name == name && x.Password == password).Any())
                return true;
                else return false;

            

        }

        public bool CheckUserExist(string name)
        {
 
                   
                if (_context.User.Any(x => x.Name == name))
                    return true;
                    else return false;


        }
        public bool AddUser(string name, string password, bool trainer)
        {
            using (var db = _context)
            {
                var user = new User { Name = name, Password = password, Trainer = trainer };

                db.User.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            
             }


        }
    }
```

program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
    opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:5001",
            ValidAudience = "https://localhost:5001",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"))
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS", builder => 
    { 
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod(); 
    });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TrainingAppContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=(Localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TrainingAppData"));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("EnableCORS");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

error in console:

> fail:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'TrainingApp.Server.Services.LoginService' while attempting to
> activate 'TrainingApp.Server.Controllers.AuthController'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method3(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
>
> C:\Engineering
> Thesis\TrainingApp.Server\TrainingApp.Server\bin\Debug\net6.0\TrainingApp.Server.exe
> (process 25696) exited with code -1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection error: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-whil)

Comment: seems like you have not registered your login service, create a contract for that(interface) then inject it to your controller it should solve the problem, also register it in your startup or programme class either as a scoped or transient

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `loginService` as an Injected Dependency, you need to register it in your dependency Container.

The exception states that it was unable to resolve the Login service when attempting to activate the `TrainingApp.Server.Controllers.AuthController`

You will need to update your `Program.cs` file and add this line:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TrainingAppContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=(Localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TrainingAppData"));

// Add this line to add the login service as a singleton in your DI
// Be sure to add this line before calling the build() function
// If you want it to be a Singleton
// One instance will be created for the lifetime of the application
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LoginService>();

// If you want it to be a Transient
// A new instance will be created each time you inject it
builder.Services.AddTransient<LoginService>();

// If you want it to be a Scoped
// One instance will be created for each HTTP Request
builder.Services.AddScoped<LoginService>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

This needs to be done for every service you want to use by Dependency Injection

Check this documentation: [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

[Difference between Scoped, Transient and Singleton](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/differences-between-scoped-transient-and-singleton-service/)

Comment: Thank you for documentation and explain, it works but not Singleton just 
builder.Services.AddTransient<LoginService>();

Comment: I updated my answer to explain a bit the difference between Transient, scoped and singleton ;)