# How do I get the DBContext in a class?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a few functions I use in multiple controllers.  I put the functions in a class so that I can use them without duplicating.

When I try to inject my DB context in the class like I do with my controllers I get:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'TMS.Functions.Tools' while attempting to activate 'TMS.Controllers.TestController'.

Edit: Full stacktrace:
[image]

Example of how I inject in my controllers, and what fails in my class:

```
private readonly TMSContext _context;

public Tools(TMSContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

This is how I inject my tools function:

```
using TMS.Functions;

namespace TMS.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class PayPortalController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<TMSUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly TMSContext _context;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly Tools _tools;

        public PayPortalController(UserManager<TMSUser> userManager
            ,RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
            ,TMSContext context
            ,IConfiguration config
            ,Tools tools)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _context = context;
            _config = config;
            _tools = tools;
        }
...
```

What is the proper way to do this for a class?

Comment: What is the full error message and stack trace?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I have added a screenshot of the stacktrace.

Comment: Please show where you register `Tools` with the container.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I believe I have added what you were asking.

Comment: No, that's where you inject it. You should have something like `services.AddTransient` or `services.AddScoped`, etc. usually in your `Program` or `Statup` file under `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Ok, that must be the piece i'm missing.  I've not done that.

Comment: This issue is you don't register your `Tools` class in the dependancy container  `services.AddScoped<Tools>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is shown when you haven't registered a class in Dependency Injection. A good answer to this error can be found here: [Dependency Injection error: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate, while class is registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-while-attempting)

You will have to register this class in the startup of your web app (in the `Program.cs` file for .NET 6).

You can see how to register services in asp.net here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0.

It will look something like this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
```

I would suggest setting up an interface for the `Tools` class and then you would register it like so:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITools, Tools>();
```

Or without the interface it would look like:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<Tools>();
```

You can use scoped, transient or singleton, depending on how long you want the service available. You can read about this here: [AddTransient, AddScoped and AddSingleton Services Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38138100/9856112)

Comment: Thanks!  Before this posted I used this link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-and-register-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core-net-6/ in case anyone needs more than whats above.