# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'PassportMVC.DBLayer.DbContextPaging'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to create/implement a new Pagination to our project, I checked the code and there is no error in the VS, however when I run the program. I got this error: [image]

It says: InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'PassportMVC.DBLayer.DbContextPaging' while attempting to activate 'PassportMVC.Controllers.HomeController'.

Here is my code in the DBLayerFolder, and I have an ApplicantsEntity.cs in my Models folder.
[image]

I tried to Clean the solution and Build, Rebuild but I'm stuck with this error, does anyone know how to resolve this or maybe have encountered it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependency Injection error: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate, while class is registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-while-attempting)

Comment: U need to post ur pagination code. If u r using the Ipagedlist like the Mvc5 type. It is no longer working for core.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .5 or a previous version, try adding this in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    // Other stuff...
    services.AddDbContext<DbContextPaging>();
}
```

if you are using .net 6 or .net 7

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContextPaging>();
```