# how to solve system.invalidoperation exception error?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dbcontext, invalidoperationexception

I have created a asp.net web api while running api I am getting this error

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'movieRentalApp.Data.DataContext' while attempting to activate 'movieRentalpp.Controllers.CustomersController'.

this is C# code for Customer class

namespace movieRentalApp.Model
{
public class Customer
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string? CustomerName { get; set; }
public string? Email { get; set; }
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
public int Phone { get; set; }
}
}

this is code for controller
namespace movieRentalApp.Model
{
public class Customer
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string? CustomerName { get; set; }
public string? Email { get; set; }
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
public int Phone { get; set; }
}
}
this is db context

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using movieRentalApp.Model;

namespace movieRentalApp.Data
{
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{

```
    }


    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Personnel> Personnels { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Rental> Rentals { get; set; }

    //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("  Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MovieRentalAppDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True, ");




}
```

}

Comment: The error is telling you that you that `DataContext` isn't registered in the DI container. have you forgotten to call `AddDbContext` in your `Program.Main` or `Startup.ConfigureServices`? If you search for the error text ` Unable to resolve service for type...` you'll find several duplicates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependency Injection error: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate, while class is registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-while-attempting)