# Dependency injection error: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate registered class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Web API. When I'm executing my API with a get request, an exception is throwing before my break point:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmvcAzHpsk8&ab_channel=LesJackson)
>
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Commander.Data.ICommanderRepo' while attempting to activate 'Commander.Controllers.CommandsController'

`CommandsController.cs`:

```
namespace Commander.Controllers
{
    // Api/commands
    [Route("api/commands")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CommandsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICommanderRepo _repository; //Dependency injected value

        public CommandsController(ICommanderRepo repository)  //Inject dependency
        {
            _repository = repository;
        } 

        //private readonly MockCommanderRepo _repository = new MockCommanderRepo();
        
        //GET api/commands 
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult <IEnumerable<Command>> GetAllCommands()
        {
            var commandItems = _repository.GetAppCommands();

            return Ok(commandItems);
        }

        //GET api/commands/{id}
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult <Command> GetCommandById(int id)
        {
            var commandItem = _repository.GetCommandById(id);
            return Ok(commandItem);
        }
    }
}
```

`ICommanderRepo.cs`:

```
namespace Commander.Data
{
    public interface ICommanderRepo
    {
        IEnumerable<Command> GetAppCommands();
        Command GetCommandById(int id);
    }
}
```

`MockCommanderRepo.cs`:

```
namespace Commander.Data
{
    public class MockCommanderRepo : ICommanderRepo
    {
        public IEnumerable<Command> GetAppCommands()
        {
            var commands = new List<Command> {
                new Command{Id=0, HowTo="Boil an egg", Line="Boil water", Platform="Kettle & Pan"},
                new Command{Id=1, HowTo="Cut bread", Line="Get a knife", Platform="Knife & chopping board"},
                new Command{Id=2, HowTo="Make cup of tea", Line="Place teabag in cup", Platform="Kettle & cup"}
            };

            return commands;
        }

        public Command GetCommandById(int id)
        {
            return new Command{Id=0, HowTo="Boil an egg", Line="Boil water", Platform="Kettle & Pan"};
        }
    }
}
```

`Command.cs`:

```
namespace Commander.Models
{
    public class Command
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string HowTo { get; set; } = default!;
        public string Line { get; set; } = default!;
        public string Platform { get; set; }  = default!;
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
namespace Commander
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            
            services.AddScoped<ICommanderRepo, MockCommanderRepo>(); //Dependency injection
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I included `services.AddScoped` in the `Startup` class and did the dependency injection in `Commander.Controllers` so I'm not sure what is the issue. When I tested with the mock repository before the dependency injection, the get request was working until I performed the dependency injection.

I'm following along this video [youtube.com/watch?v=fmvcAzHpsk8&ab_channel=LesJackson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmvcAzHpsk8&ab_channel=LesJackson) at 51:30 who built the API in .NET 3.1 but I'm using .NET 8.0.0 so I'm not sure if that will make any difference if the implementation is still fine?

Can anyone help with this error? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Your API Controller depends on the scoped service ICommanderRepo.  In your Startup, in ConfigureServices, add the dependency before the controllers. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-while-attempting

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper - the order of adding to the DI container doesn’t matter (except for collections of the same service type).

Comment: @Clarissa - it looks basically sound. Do you perhaps have 2 `ICommanderRepo` interfaces in different namespaces?

Comment: @sellotape - The only interface is in ICommanderRepo.cs. I'm following along this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmvcAzHpsk8&ab_channel=LesJackson who built the API in .NET 3.1 but I'm using .NET 8.0.0 so I'm not sure if that will make any difference if the implementation is still fine?

Comment: Should be fine; there have been many changes but nothing breaking of note affecting what I see there.  I just downloaded [his repo](https://github.com/binarythistle/S03E02---.NET-Core-3.1-MVC-REST-API.git), changed to `<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>`, swapped the `ICommanderRepo` to be a `MockCommanderRepo` as yours is, built and ran in .NET8 preview 6 and it worked fine.  There must be something else going on we can't see above.  Try the above, and if his works, try comparing his repo to yours.

Comment: I test your code in my .net 7 web api project, I don't have the startup.cs file, so I just add the configuration code in program.cs, and everything worked fine... could you pls help check by putting all your codes in program.cs instead of the startup file?

Comment: Able to share your program.cs file as well?

Comment: I changed my Program.cs to his code and now I get "Unhandled exception.  System.NotSupportedException: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IStartup isn't supported."

Comment: Turns out I had <StartupBase> instead of <Startup> in Program.cs. I finally caught the error. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `Startup.cs` is created but its not configured in `Program.cs`.

The following lines of code need to be added in `Program.cs`

```
var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);
startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services); // calling ConfigureServices method
```

Following is the complete `Program.cs` code.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//start up class
var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration); 
startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services); // calling ConfigureServices method
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```