# System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'IAuthenticationService' while attempting to activate 'Controller'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ElectronicsShop.Services.Interfaces.IAuthenticationService' while attempting to activate 'ElectronicsShop.Controllers.UserController'.

Here is program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using ElectronicsShop.Data;
using ElectronicsShop.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option =>
{
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultSQLConnection"));
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
            ValidIssuer = configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
        };
    });


builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Wedding Planner API", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = @"JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n 
                      Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.
                      \r\n\r\nExample: 'Bearer 12345abcdef'",
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "Bearer",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            },
            new List<string>()
        }
    });
});

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAngularDevClient",
        b =>
        {
            b
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});


var app = builder.Build();


if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors("AllowAngularDevClient");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Here is Controller:

```
using AuthenticationApi.Services;
using ElectronicsShop.Models;
using ElectronicsShop.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ElectronicsShop.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

        public UserController(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
        {
            _authenticationService = authenticationService;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("login")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(string))]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginRequest request)
        {
            var response = await _authenticationService.Login(request);

            return Ok(response);
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("register")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(string))]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterRequest request)
        {
            var response = await _authenticationService.Register(request);

            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is service

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using ElectronicsShop.Entities;
using ElectronicsShop.Models;
using ElectronicsShop.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace AuthenticationApi.Services;

public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public AuthenticationService(UserManager<User> userManager, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task<string> Register(RegisterRequest request)
    {
        var userByEmail = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);
        var userByUsername = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);
        if (userByEmail is not null || userByUsername is not null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"User with email {request.Email} or username {request.Username} already exists.");
        }

        User user = new()
        {
            Email = request.Email,
            UserName = request.Username,
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, request.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Unable to register user {request.Username} errors: {GetErrorsText(result.Errors)}");
        }

        return await Login(new LoginRequest { Username = request.Email, Password = request.Password });
    }

    public async Task<string> Login(LoginRequest request)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);

        if (user is null)
        {
            user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Username);
        }

        if (user is null || !await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, request.Password))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Unable to authenticate user {request.Username}");
        }

        var authClaims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
            new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        };
        var token = GetToken(authClaims);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }

    private JwtSecurityToken GetToken(IEnumerable<Claim> authClaims)
    {
        var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
            audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
            claims: authClaims,
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));

        return token;
    }

    private string GetErrorsText(IEnumerable<IdentityError> errors)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", errors.Select(error => error.Description).ToArray());
    }
}
```

I checked dependency injection because i found that this could be a problem but it seems fine.

Comment: This is an exception resolving the service using dependency injection.  Check out this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-while-attempting

Comment: I see that `AuthenticationService` asks for a `UserManager`. Could it be that instanciating a `UserManager` in some form requires a `UserController` instance (static field or something) which leads to a dependency cycle? And where does the `UserManager` come from, how can DI create that object?

Comment: Based on the error which indicates an issue with dependency injection where the "UserController" can't find the "IAuthenticationService" it needs. Double-check the namespace, registration, constructor injection, service lifetime, configuration, and clear the cache. If necessary, create a minimal test controller to isolate the issue.