# DotNet API: Dependency Injection error: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I created an .NET Core MVC application and use Dependency Injection and Repository Pattern to inject a repository to my controller. However, I am getting an error:

`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'BlogApi.Models.IBlogRepository' while attempting to activate 'BlogApi.Controllers.BlogController'.`

This is the same issue to this post: [The Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-while-attempting)

in my **controller**, I have

```
public class BlogController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBlogRepository _blogRepository;

    public BlogController(IBlogRepository blogRepository)
    {
        _blogRepository = blogRepository;
    }
}
```

**startup**

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));

    services.AddScoped<IBlogRepository, BlogRepository>();

    services.AddControllers();
    
}
```

**BlogRepository**

```
public class BlogRepository : IBlogRepository
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public BlogRepository(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Blog>> Search(string name)
    {
        return await _context.Blogs
            .Where(b => b.Name.Contains(name))
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

**IBlogRepository**

```
public interface IBlogRepository
{
    // Search blogs by name
    Task<IEnumerable<Blog>> Search(string name);
}
```

Still getting the error.. IDK where it went wrong

Comment: Can you also provide the code of both `IBlogRepository` and `BlogRepository`?

Comment: there is no issue in this code, i think so there must be issue in your class or interface implementation. if you could provide the implementation it would be easy to figure out the issue. have you implemented the interface?

Comment: added, do take a look.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// BlogController.cs
public class BlogController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBlogRepository _blogRepository;

    public BlogController(IBlogRepository blogRepository)
    {
        _blogRepository = blogRepository;
    }

    // ... your controller actions go here
}

// Startup.cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));

        services.AddScoped<IBlogRepository, BlogRepository>();

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // ... other startup configurations go here
}

// BlogRepository.cs
public class BlogRepository : IBlogRepository
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public BlogRepository(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Blog>> Search(string name)
    {
        return await _context.Blogs
            .Where(b => b.Name.Contains(name))
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}

// IBlogRepository.cs
public interface IBlogRepository
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Blog>> Search(string name);
}
```

Ensure that the AddScoped<IBlogRepository, BlogRepository>() registration is done in the ConfigureServices method of your Startup.cs class before the services.AddControllers() line. This should help resolve the dependency injection issue.