# ASP.NET Core Web API : System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Normally this means for me I failed to inject the interface and repository in `program.cs`, however I did do that and it still seems to fail. Not sure what I'm missing I stepped through everything. Up for over 24 hours so I do need another set of eyes.

`program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IXFer, XFerRepository>();
```

`xFerRepository.cs`:

```
public class XFerRepository : IXFer
{
     private readonly dbContext context;

     public XFerRepository(dbContext context)
     {
         this.context = context;
     }

     public async Task<XFer> CreateAsync(XFer transaction)
     {
         await context.Xfers.AddAsync(transaction);
         await context.SaveChangesAsync();
         return transaction;
     }

     public async Task<IEnumerable<XFer>> GetAllAsync()
     {
         return await context.Xfers.ToListAsync();
     }
}
```

`IXfer.cs` (interface)

```
public interface IXFer
{
    Task<IEnumerable<XFer>> GetAllAsync();
    Task<XFer> CreateAsync(XFer transaction);
}
```

`XFerController.cs`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class XFerController : ControllerBase
{
     private readonly XFerRepository transactionRepository;

     public XFerController(XFerRepository transactionRepository)
     {
         this.transactionRepository = transactionRepository;
     }

     [HttpGet]
     public async Task<IActionResult> GetTransactions()
     {
         var transactions = await transactionRepository.GetAllAsync();
         var response = new List<XFer>();

         // sending transaction model
         foreach (var transaction in transactions)
         {
             response.Add(new XFer
             {
                 id = transaction.id,
                 transactionType = transaction.transactionType,
                 amount = transaction.amount,
                 transactionDate = transaction.transactionDate
             });
         }
         //response = response.OrderByDescending(o => o.transactionDate).ToList();

         return Ok(response);
     }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependency Injection error: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate, while class is registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-while-attempting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told your DI container how to provide the interface but your controller constructor takes the concrete type.

Comment: damn, I got caught by the "I" again... it was a long day and night, still no sleep.  Thank you for the quick response.