# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationRoot' while attempting to activate 'TheWorld.Startup'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Seems like I'm having some sort of mismatching reference problem (Sorry, Im very new on the ASP version).

Im using VS 2016 creating an ASP.core app from scratch. My startup class goes like:

```
public class Startup
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment _env;
        private IConfigurationRoot _config;

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IConfigurationRoot config)
        {
            _env = env;

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(_env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("config.json");

            _config = builder.Build();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(_config);

            if(_env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
               services.AddScoped<Services.IMailServices, Services.DebugMailService>();

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            if(env.IsDevelopment())
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc(config =>
            {
                config.MapRoute(name: "Default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
                );
             });
        }
    }
```

Im having a hard time with the 'IConfigurationRoot' though. I've added its reference via IDE, and the project.json looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.3",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions":  "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
```

You guys can spot any silly mistake(s) in here?

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net Core MVC Dependency Injection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801831/asp-net-core-mvc-dependency-injection-not-working)

Answer (score 16):

Use IConfiguration instead of IConfigurationIRoot

Answer (score 5):

cast it like below:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
     Configuration = (IConfigurationRoot) configuration;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The IConfigurationRoot is an interface which inherits from IConfiguration as below:

```
interface IConfigurationRoot : IConfiguration
```

So you need to use IConfiguration as the type specified in TServic.

Service type should be IConfiguration type and not IConfigurationRoot.

To add access to configuration, replace the below line:

```
services.AddSingleton(_config);
```

With:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(_config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify that line .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath) instead of .SetBasePath(_env.ContentRootPath) ....
Is this the code scaffolded by Visual Studio ???

Answer (score -1):

When I encountered this error, closing and re-opening Visual Studio fixed the problem.